# Can't hide a DIV

Tags: javascript, css

I'm going bananas here because when I execute the following code:

```
myDiv.className += condition ? " green" : " red hidden";
console.log("class: " + myDiv.className);
```

I get to see the text as supposed to. In fact, I even **see** the red border around my thingy! However, for some (for me explainable) reason, the component is still visible. It's either divine intervention intended on ruining my Christmas or I'm missing something extremely basic due to fatigue. Which is it? Does God hate me, now? :)

```
.hidden{ display: none; }
.green{ border: 3px solid #00bb00; }
.red{ border: 3px solid #dd0000; }
```

Comment: Do you have any other styles on the element? Any inline styles (`myDiv.style._____`)? Any `!important` rules?

Comment: Look in your browser's developer tools to inspect the element after adding that class. You should be able to see a list of all the matching css \rules.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've there before without seeing anything. But your reply made me think and in fact, when I go to the DOM editor, the class *hidden* isn't there (neither is *red* so it beats me when that border comes from (no redness anywhere in my CSS). When I type in *hidden*, the DIV behaves like supposed to, though. So the question is why on Earth the *className* doesn't get updated (I got tricked by the red thinking that it comes from that call).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski My bad - *red* is there, actually. But not *hidden*. WTF?! How can that assignment give this behavior? I've renamed the classes like *wroom* and "hrmp* to ensure that there's no collisions with others. Still, the same behavior...

Comment: Would you post a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, because I'm recognizing the symptoms here. Are you by any chance involved in a bigger project, programming a large solution (EpiServer, SharePoint or something like that) and there is JavaScript code that isn't yours?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I've tried that and it does what it's supposed to. So my question is what I can do to resolve it on my system. And I can't post the code because it's CRM, a MS-stuff that you plug script a little bit here and there. Really nasty. :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, it's Dynamics CRM. Or maybe - yes, depending on what you meant by "like that").

Comment: What happens if you change red in your code to something else? Is the final result still red?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals Nope. **that** style is affected and remains. It's the *hidden* that gets hidden. But I just got a suggestions from Konrad and  Jonathan that might be the key. I'll go and reply to them. Such stuff should **not** happen two days before Christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably is an other script that runs and removes the class named *hidden* (quite common name) and my guess is that whoever wrote that code, selects the elements by class, not by id. So probably, that person has an unintentionally wide scope of the removal.

Check the remains of the class names. You've got a space at the end. That's pretty strong suggestion that there **has been** something but was removed. (Extra minus to the coder for not removing the space).

You should talk to that programmer and explain how to do his operation more safely.

[image: This man has thought me a new thing!]

Comment: And there we go... Yes, there's a JavaScript code that runs and edits all components of class *step* (not *hidden* but it's still the same idea). I know who wrote that code but I won't talk to him. I don't like talking to myself. :(

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that some other selector is outweighing your `.hidden` class in its specificity. For instance, consider the following code:

```
​var myDiv = document.querySelector("#foo");
myDiv.className = (false) ? "grn" : "red hidden";
```

In this example, like yours, the result is a `className` of `red hidden`, applying both of the following:

```
.hidden { display: none }
.red { border: 2px solid red }
```

But my element is still visible:

[image]

When I inspect the styles of this element, it's clear what the problem is - I have a more specific selecto `#foo` in this case that is overruling the `.hidden` class:

[image]

Another option could be that you have similar scripting in another place, further modifying the `className` of this element. You could insert a debugging point using the `debugger` keyword, and then step through the execution of your code on your page.

Comment: I'm going crazy. This is what I see there: `<div class="red " id="myDiv">` and there are no strike-throughs in the right pane. Only the *.red* class with everything in it. The *.hidden* is, well... it's hidden somehow. :)

Comment: @AndreasJohansson There must be more code at play; do you get the correct results when you visit my demo online at http://jsfiddle.net/n2NyB/show/? Also, do you have similar logic anywhere else on your page? Is it possible that `.red` and `.hidden` *are* getting set, but something else is replacing them later on with just `.red`?

Comment: @AndreasJohansson Try entering `debugger;` into your JavaScript code and proceed to step through execution. This should reveal where, in your code, the `.hidden` is being removed (as well as confirming that it *is* being applied).

Comment: Yer're right on. As I wrote to @KonradViltersten above, it's an evil JS execution that an idiot didn't limited to the right set of components. That stupid moron would be me a week ago. One should take responsibility for the code one writes if there's been more than a day or two, right? Huge thanks to everybody! ;)

Comment: @AndreasJohansson So pleased to hear that I could help. Merry Christmas ;) Try not to lose your mind before the New Year. Hehe.

Comment: How do you get the images there? It's way more pedagogical but when I trie to enter the site *i-stack.igmur* (hoping to register and post images myself), I get nada. Hints?

Comment: @KonradViltersten When editing your answer you will see a button to upload/insert imagery.

Comment: Oh my dearest God. This was embarrassing. And it **still** took me a few minutes to actually see that icon **even with** your explanation! Talking about *hiding in plain sight*. Or *being very, very dumb*, haha. I guess I'm such a hard-core coder that icons just woosh pass me unnoticed. Everything important in life and universe can and must be expressed as XML. I'm expressing my respects and gratitude by honoring you a place in my my answer being edited. Now, you're eternal! :)